# Ambiguous Occurrence

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I am currently learning how to write type classes. I can't seem to write the Ord type class with compile errors of ambiguous occurrence.

```
module Practice where

class  (Eq a) => Ord a  where
    compare              :: a -> a -> Ordering
    (<), (<=), (>=), (>) :: a -> a -> Bool
    max, min             :: a -> a -> a

    -- Minimal complete definition:
    --      (<=) or compare
    -- Using compare can be more efficient for complex types.
    compare x y
         | x == y    =  EQ
         | x <= y    =  LT
         | otherwise =  GT

    x <= y           =  compare x y /= GT
    x <  y           =  compare x y == LT
    x >= y           =  compare x y /= LT
    x >  y           =  compare x y == GT

    -- note that (min x y, max x y) = (x,y) or (y,x)
    max x y 
         | x <= y    =  y
         | otherwise =  x
    min x y
         | x <= y    =  x
         | otherwise =  y
```

Errors are

```
Practice.hs:26:14:
    Ambiguous occurrence `<='
    It could refer to either `Practice.<=', defined at Practice.hs:5:10
                          or `Prelude.<=',
                             imported from `Prelude' at Practice.hs:1:8-15
...
```

and so on. I think it is clashing with the Prelude defined version.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that the names of your functions are clashing with the standard ones from the Prelude.

To solve this, you can add an explicit import declaration which hides the conflicting names:

```
module Practice where

import Prelude hiding (Ord, compare, (<), (<=), (>=), (>), max, min)

...
```

Answer (score 19):

hammar is right, it's because of clashing with standard Prelude names. But there are another solutions in addition to `hiding` names from Prelude.

You can import Prelude qualified:

```
module Practice where

import qualified Prelude as P

...
```

Next, you can gain access to both you and standard version of function: `max` will execute your version, and `P.max` will execute standard Prelude's.

There is also way to completely hide all standard Prelude functions: GHC's extension NoImplicitPrelude (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/No_import_of_Prelude). It can be activated writing

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
```

in the very beginning of your file

Comment: Thanks! For my situation, practicing to define exp operation for the complex number, I have to hide `import Prelude hiding (div, abs, exp)` but at the same time to make Prelude.exp accessible by `import qualified Prelude as P -- to be able to use P.exp`